# Wrong BigInteger result using hibernate native query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using Hibernate4 + PostgresSql.
I need to get a list of ids from my DB without getting a whole object.
I use a native query (because it's hierarchical) and it looks like:

```
String s = hierachical_part_skipped +"select id " +
                "from search_hierarchy " +
                "order by id";

Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(s);
List<Long> resList = new ArrayList<>();
List<BigInteger> biglist = q.getResultList();
for (Object id : biglist) {
    System.out.print(id+",");
    resList.add(id.longValue());
}
```

Well, 1 time out of three my bigList is filled with wrong values!
I have
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ... 27350
instead of
1, 2... 2735
(a zero is added to each value).
Native query executed manually not through Hibernate returns correct values.

I've tried retrieving result as List of Object, but the result was the same

Comment: Drop a trigger that multiplies id value by ten.

Comment: @Roman C, what trigger are you talking about and why is it working only sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a sufficient workaround

```
s.append("select id \\:\\:numeric " + //that's a hack
      "from search_department " +
      "order by id");
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(s);
List<Long> resList = new ArrayList<>();
List<BigDecimal> biglist = q.getResultList();
for (BigDecimal id : biglist) {
    System.out.print(id + ",");
    resList.add(id.longValue());
}
```

Still, I'm wondering why BigInteger works incorrectly

Comment: I have the same issue with postgres db